# Select the latest entry from two tables?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Now the title might be a bit confusing, it is hard to explain in just a few words.

So I have the table Topics and Posts. Both have the row "posted" which represents the time the thread/post was posted. What I would need to do is to compare these and just choose one entry and that entry is the latest one.

I can kinda demonstrate what I mean. I have like this now.

```
$postsQ = $DB->query("SELECT t.posted, p.userid, p.topicid, t.id FROM posts p, topics t WHERE t.forumid = '$ForumSub[id]' AND t.id = p.topicid ORDER BY t.posted DESC LIMIT 1,1");
```

Not the best code I know.

I KNOW THIS DOESN'T WORK but to show the idea of what I want, here is how the query could look

```
$postsQ = $DB->query("SELECT (p.posted AND t.posted) AS tpposted, p.userid, p.topicid, t.id FROM posts p, topics t WHERE t.forumid = '$ForumSub[id]' AND t.id = p.topicid ORDER BY tpposted DESC LIMIT 1,1");
```

Anyone know how I can achieve this?

Comment: Please edit your question and include sample data and desired results.

Comment: you want the most recent post in the most recent topic?

Comment: @pala_ I want the most recent of both. Like if a thread was just recently created, I want the timestamp for the thread. And if a post was created even more recently, I want the timestamp for the post. So I basically want the most recent out of both.

Comment: are you averse to just executing two queries? once for most recent post, once for most recent topic?

Comment: @pala_ You mean doing two queries and then comparing them to see which is the most recent? That is a possibility but feels like there is a better way. But ofc if that is the tip/help I get that is definitely an option.

Comment: ah so you want only one response, topic or post, whichever is most recent? do you need any additional info or JUST the timestamp?

Comment: The timestamp and the creator. Creator is stored as "userid" and the timestamp as "posted" (UNIX Timestamp if it makes any difference)

Comment: and last question, does it need to indicate if its a topic, or if its a post?

Comment: @pala_ no, that is not necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply union homogenised versions of the tables together, and then sort them in descending order by `posted` and limit the result.  Try this:

```
select *
  from
    (
      select id, posted, userid, 'post'
        from posts
      union
        select id, posted, userid, 'topic'
          from topics
    ) q
  order by posted desc limit 1;
```

With a demonstration fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b46c2/1